# Is it possible to dynamically select assemblies to build in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

In my company there is single repo for all projects. I want to create build pipeline, but then all assemblies would need to be build each time someone push some code. Building all assemblies takes to much time so instead i would like to restrict them to only those which were changed. Is it possible in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it sounds like your repo is very large containing multiple projects and/or solutions with some form of dependencies.  If you don't want to re-build everything then you need to just build deltas.

Basically you continue to build everything but with certain controls:

1. don't clean source and output folders
2. don't use the `rebuild` msbuild target instead use `build`
3. lock it down to a known build agent

In this way subsequent builds take advantage of prior built binaries without re-building them thus vastly reducing build time.

However it's probably not a good idea and is likely not fixing any underlying problem in your repo design.  Your builds could very well be including stale artefacts if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can define the build trigger, on a path of your repository, with path filter

https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/09/19/using-path-filters-in-build-definition-in-azure-devops-vsts/

[image]

Comment: All you are doing is forcing a limit of the repo ahead of time to some known path.  It **won't** prevent excessive projects from being built.   e.g. Assuming `/myproject`  includes 50 projects in child folders and I change a single file, _**all 50 will be re-built.**_.   Your path specification also prevents other projects from being built if a user changes a file in the repo in say `/someotherfolder`

Comment: yes for the git-clone, but you can specify not to clean the source directory, but just do a pull. [Get Source] >>  [clean] = false  and have multi-pipeline build, configure by path filters